# Listen Music when the other side person recive my call

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I want to create application in android in which i can listen music to the other side person...for that i have written code..in that code ....when phone state goes to OFFHOOK mode music start automatic....but there is problem with that.....music start even though phone has not been recived....means when phone is dialing....at the same time music start....i want music should start when the other side of person  receive call.......

thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this (not on my workstation), but I think you could check for the phone state CALL_STATE_RINGING and start the music when the state changes from this to CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK, this should mean that the call has been answered.

Comment: I have used CALL_STATE_RINGING and CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK but when I dial a number phone state goes to OFFHOOK mode and music start even though the other side person doesn't receive my call....so i want to get that state of phone when the other side person receive my call...if he/she doesn't receive a call music should not be start.....

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, CALL_STATE_RINGING is used only for incoming calls. How about checking if android.provider.CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall(context) updates it's DURATION in realtime and starts from 0 when a call is answered? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html)